# create terraform hcl variable as a map

Tags: terraform

I am working on terraform workspace automation using `tfe` provider and want to create a terraform HCL variable as a map using `custom_tags` from the below data structure.

```
workspaces = {
  "PROD" = {
    "custom_tags" = {
      "Application" = "demo"
      "EnvironmentType" = "prod"
      "NamePrefix" = "sof"
      "ProductType" = "terraform"
    }
    "env_variables" = {}
    "id" = "alfsdfksf"
    "name" = "PROD"
    "repo" = "github/something"
    "tf_variables" = {}
  }
  "UAT" = {
    "custom_tags" = {
      "Application" = "demo"
      "EnvironmentType" = "uat"
      "NamePrefix" = "sof"
      "ProductType" = "terraform"
    }
    "env_variables" = {}
    "id" = "ws-k7KWYfsdfsdf"
    "name" = "UAT"
    "repo" = "github/otherthing"
    "tf_variables" = {}
  }
}
```

Here is my resource block

```
resource "tfe_variable" "terraform_hcl_variables" {
  for_each     = { for w in local.workspaces : w.name => w }
  key          = "custom_tags"
  value        = each.value.custom_tags
  category     = "terraform"
  hcl          = true
  sensitive    = false
  workspace_id = tfe_workspace.main[each.key].id
}
```

And, I am getting this error. Any help is appreciated to resolve this.

```
**each.value.custom_tags is object with 4 attributes
Inappropriate value for attribute "value": string required.**
```

**Expected outcome**

custom_tags should be created as a HCL variable

```
custom_tags = 
{
   "Application" = "demo"
   "EnvironmentType" = "prod"
   "NamePrefix" = "sof"
   "ProductType" = "terraform"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly you can't do this. `value` attribute **must be string**, but you are trying to assign an "object with 4 attributes" to it.

You could convert your `each.value.custom_tags` into string using [jsonencode](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/jsonencode.html), but this is probably not what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: @doubledecker No problem. Did you manage to sort this out?

Comment: I managed to add all the custom tags (application, environment, name prefix, product type) into the workspace. and used  value using something like this `each.value.application`  and assigned value as a single string. Very basic, redundant but it worked for me.

here is the value from resource block

`value        = "{\n\"EnvironmentType\" = \"${each.value.environment}\"\n \"Application\" = \"${each.value.application}\"\n \"ProductType\" = \"${var.application}\"\n \"NamePrefix\" = \"${var.name_prefix}\"\n}"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
workspace_id = tfe_workspace.main[each.key].workspace_id
```